# How would I go about applying some sort of dynamic range counter to jQuery and CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

The gist of what I'm trying to achieve here is to have a list of articles where the headline is clickable and extends and div class via jQuery. As it is presently, it sort of works in that it applies this effect to everything simultaneously, but this obviously isn't desired.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.expand").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".remainder").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
a.expand {}

.remainder {
  display: none;
}
```

XHTML:

```
<ul class="shows">
  <li class="show">
    <div class="showInfo alignLeft">
      <h3><a href="" class="expand">Some Band @ Some Venue</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="showDate alignRight"><h3>00/00/0000</h3></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="1" class="remainder">
      w/ Some Other Band. Cover is $ and doors are at 00:00.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any helps would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do what you are after is to target only the anchor that is being clicked. To do that you can use `$(this)`.

Here is what the jQuery would look like:

```
var $expand = $('.expand');

$expand.on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).closest('.show').find('.remainder').slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

I cached the `$('.expand')` selector to increase performance.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/8RwJN/
​

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you have multiple sets of these and `$(".remainder").slideToggle("fast");` is affecting all of them then you need to change it to

`$(this).parents('.show').children('.remainder').slideToggle("fast");`

Comment: Your selector `show` and `remainder` should be `.show` and `.remainder`. Also, I would use `closest` instead of `parents`.

Comment: @YanickRochon: Thanks. `.closest()` will not work in this case as it only travels up the dom tree.

Comment: @Morin, yes, and `.show` is a parent of `$(this)` so it works